# RoR: Missing template when trying to use AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

### ISSUE :(

I am trying to implement AJAX the RoR way, but I get the following message after the the form is submitted.

> #### Template is missing
>
> Missing template points/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "PATH_TO_APP/survivor-fantasyleague/app/views"

### SETUP

1. the form tag that is submitted is generated via `<%= form_tag('/points', remote: true) %>` is `<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/points" data-remote="true" enctype="text/javascript" method="post">`
2. I have a `create` action which the form submits to. At the end of the action is:

   > respond_to { |format| format.html; format.js { } }
3. `create`'s view is `create.js.erb` which is in the correct view subfolder. It contains 3 lines of JQuery.

---

Note: When I replace `format.html` with `format.html { render <THING_TO_RENDER> }`, it reloads the whole page and renders the "THING_TO_RENDER"

Hopefully I'm just not understanding something basic as this is my first shot at using AJAX, ever.

Also, The info I do have came from the few tutorials (ex. RoR Guides) that I could find.

Thanks.

Comment: it is not sending the request as `js`, do you have `rails.js` included in your pages? it can be found [here](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js)

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you very much! If you add that as an answer I will mark it as such -- if that's the protocol lol

Comment: nice..added it as a answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not sending the request as js, do you have rails.js included in your pages? it can be found [here](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js)